# Creating EKEvent with Unique Identifier(Not Editable)

Tags: ios, swift, ekevent, ekeventstore

I want to create an EKEvent to add it in device calendar. Is there any way to set a unique id (which a user can not edit in Calendar app) to this event so that I can identify or match it with my event.

I am creating event like this

```
let event = EKEvent.init(eventStore: eventStore)
event.title = "My location"
event.location = "Location Address"

// Setting Start - End Date
event.startDate = Date()
event.endDate = Date()

do {
    // Saving Events
    try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
    let message = "Schedule has been added to your device's calendar."
    showAlert(title: kFVApplicationTitle, message: message)
} catch {
    let message = "Schedule could not be added to your device's calendar."
    showAlert(title: kFVApplicationTitle, message: message)
}
```

Comment: `EventKit` creates an unique identifier (`eventIdentifier`) implicitly while initializing the object. Isn't that sufficient?

Comment: No Actually I want to show a calendar button in my UI if my custom event object is not present in device calendar. To match calendar event with my custom event I need a unique Key which I can not set to EKEvent.

Comment: (eventIdentifier) is readonly I want to set it to future comparison.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creating a Category for EKEvent and adding additional properties in it solves my problem.

Comment: Glad that you found a solution, would you mind sharing it with the community?

Comment: thx for the reply! Do you mean a static key? because as far as I know, an extension cannot contain stored properties..

Comment: Sorry For misunderstanding You need to create a category not extension. Also I was talking about Objective-C.
I have deleted my previous comments to make it clear. :)

Comment: @MuhammadKhaliqurRehman what do you mean by creating category for EKEvent? Could you share example with code, please? Thank you;)